# Why does installing zfsutils-linux uninstall zfs-fuse?

Tags: zfs

I'm using 21.04 on amd64.

Why do these packages conflict? Which one *should* I use?
All I want to do is mount a zfs pool on /var/snap/snapd. Nothing fancy.

```
root@kvm:/var/snap/snapd# apt install zfs-fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvpair3linux libuutil3linux libzfs4linux libzpool4linux
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  nfs-kernel-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zfs-fuse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
Need to get 787 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,917 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Are we to answer for our release? and you are to rely on *hope* that the *breaks* rules that apply to our releases are the same for yours (each release has it's own rules; and you didn't provide any specifics as to product/release).

Comment: Because the package you're installing does the same job as the old (to be removed) packages, and the old packages would interfere with the functioning of the new (serve the same port, manage the same resource,  ...). When the kernel wants a module to support ZFS, it only allows one choice.

Comment: OK. Which is the recommended or modern set of packages?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @guiverc However this question also applies to Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, as I can confirm here. Should we edit the question? Do we need your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I need to know the answer for a production Ubuntu 22.04 instance.
Which package zfs-fuse or zfsutils-linux will have the best testing and LTS support?